# How get value from sqLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

I've got a RecyclerView and in the adapter I need to get a value from my sqLite database. More exactly here:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SimpleViewHolder holder, int position) {
        shOperations = new ShortcutsOperations(DrawerActivity.instance);
        shOperations.open();

        List values = shOperations.getAllShortcuts();
        try {
            icon = DrawerActivity.instance.getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(name.get(position)); 
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        holder.title.setImageDrawable(icon);
        final View itemView = holder.itemView;

    }
```

"name" it's which I need. My database has only 2 columns, One called ID and the other called NAME. How can I retrieve the correct value from the database in the adapter to set correctly my image in the `ImageView`?

Comment: Do you have this `name` on your SQLite?

Answer (score 0):

If the question is only about "How to fetch data from SQLite database", then I think you can use the SQLite Helper classes to query your SQLite database to fetch the required data inside the Adapter.

Hope this is what you were looking for.